# Caching intermediate results in Spark ML pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

Lately I'm planning to migrate my standalone python ML code to spark. The ML pipeline in `spark.ml` turns out quite handy, with streamlined API for chaining up algorithm stages and hyper-parameter grid search.

Still, I found its support for one important feature obscure in existing documents: **caching of intermediate results**. The importance of this feature arise when the pipeline involves computation intensive stages.

For example, in my case I use a huge sparse matrix to perform multiple moving averages on time series data in order to form input features. The structure of the matrix is determined by some hyper-parameter. This step turns out to be a bottleneck for the entire pipeline because I have to construct the matrix in runtime.

During parameter search, I usually have other parameters to examine other than this "structure parameter". So if I can reuse the huge matrix when the "structure parameter" is unchanged, I can save tons of time. For this reason, I intentionally formed my code to cache and reuse these intermediate results.

So my question is: **can Spark's ML pipeline handle intermediate caching automatically**? Or do I have to manually form code to do so? If so, is there any best practice to learn from?

P.S. I have looked into the official document and some other material, but none of them seems to discuss this topic.

Answer (score 12):

So I ran into the same problem and the way I solved is that I have implemented my own PipelineStage, that caches the input DataSet and returns it as it is.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.{DefaultParamsWritable, Identifiable}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

class Cacher(val uid: String) extends Transformer with DefaultParamsWritable {
  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = dataset.toDF.cache()

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = schema

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("CacherTransformer"))
}
```

To use it then you would do something like this:

```scala
new Pipeline().setStages(Array(stage1, new Cacher(), stage2))
```

Comment: I guess the only issue with this is solution (that I actually upvoted!) is that you don't unpersist the previsously cached dataframe (if you link several Cacher). You might argue that it's not a problem because Spark automatically unpersists at GC time, but it can get quite confusing from your UI e.g. seeing so many cached data.