# Is cross-validation faster without using pipelines in spark-ml?

Tags: pyspark, pipeline, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

Suppose I have many steps in my feature engineering: I would have many transformers in my pipeline. I am wondering how is Spark handling these transformers during the cross-validation of the pipeline: are they executed for each fold? Would it be faster to apply the transformers before cross-validating the model?

Which of these workflow would be the fastest (or is there a better solution)?:

#### 1. Cross validator on pipeline

```py
transformer1 = ...
transformer2 = ...
transformer3 = ...
lr = LogisticRegression(...)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[transformer1, transformer2, transformer3, lr])
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, numFolds=10, ...)

cvModel = crossval.fit(training)
prediction = cvModel.transform(test)
```

#### 2. Cross validator after pipeline

```py
transformer1 = ...
transformer2 = ...
transformer3 = ...
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[transformer1, transformer2, transformer3])
training_trans = pipeline.fit(training).transform(training)

lr = LogisticRegression(...)
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, numFolds=10, ...)

cvModel = crossval.fit(training_trans)
prediction = cvModel.transform(test)
```

Finally, I have the same question with using caching: In **2.** I could cache training_trans before doing my cross validation. In **1.** I could use a `Cacher` transformer in the pipeline before the LogisticRegression. (see [Caching intermediate results in Spark ML pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561687/caching-intermediate-results-in-spark-ml-pipeline) for the Cacher)

Comment: Second approach is wrong. You are first transforming your data and then doing cross-validation which will split the already transformed data into train and test and use that for prediction which will lead to data leakage to LR about the test data. First approach is correct.

Comment: @VivekKumar Do we agree it depends on the transformer ? There would be data leakage only if the transformer puts information from train into test, which is not true of all transformer (eg StringIndexer)

Comment: Yes. If the transformer is not storing anything about data during `fit()` then I would say it would be safe.

Answer (score 1):

As per a recent spark.ml training I attended - it was advised to follow this approach:

```
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,..)
pipelineModel = Pipeline(stages=[idx,assembler,cv])
cv_model= pipelineModel.fit(train)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have made the experiment but I'm still interested if anyone can give a more detailed answer.

```py
%%time
pipeline1 = Pipeline(stages=stringIndexers+oneHotEncoders+[vectorAssembler])
train2 = pipeline1.fit(train).transform(train)
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=logisticRegression, ...)
crossval.fit(train2)
```

> CPU times: user 508 ms, sys: 136 ms, total: 644 ms / Wall time: 2min 2s

```py
%%time
pipeline1 = Pipeline(stages=stringIndexers+oneHotEncoders+[vectorAssembler])
train2 = pipeline1.fit(train).transform(train)
train2.cache().count()
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=logisticRegression, ...)
crossval.fit(train2)
```

> CPU times: user 560 ms, sys: 104 ms, total: 664 ms / Wall time: 1min 25s

```py
%%time
pipeline2 = Pipeline(stages=stringIndexers+oneHotEncoders+[vectorAssembler, logisticRegression])
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline2, ...)
crossval.fit(train)
```

> CPU times: user 2.06 s, sys: 504 ms, total: 2.56 s  / Wall time: 3min